# Spatial coordinates - How to convert DMS coordinates to WGS84/UTM coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system

Work colleagues handling on-site surveys unusually collected survey points with DMS coordinates such as : N15°58.796'. Usually they sending us points with WGS84/UTM coordinates. I would ask how I convert DMS coordinates to WGS84/UTM coordinates? And specifically to WGS84/UTM zone 20N (EPSG 32620).

Comment: Converting to DMS to decimal degrees is basic math.  Converting DD to UTM meters (and vice-versa) is trivial when using GIS software. Please [Edit] your question to provide the GIS software you are using, the steps you have taken, and what problem you are encountering.

Comment: Your example latitude is in degrees & decimal minutes (not DMS).

Comment: Note: Your sample is degree decimal minutes. DMS would be N15°58'47.76".

Answer (score 1):

There are many great tools for converting coordinates on the web.
[Earth Point](http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx) is good one that accepts many different formats.